# Edit a configuration file using bash script

Tags: sed

I have a bash script that needs to modify `.ssh/config`. My goal is to change the `HostName` value of `server1` using `sed` and I have already managed to do it, but in the file there are more `HostName` and `sed` modifies them all. I have tried specifying to `sed` to stop at the first occurrence but continues to modify them all.

This is the file where I need to change the `HostName` of `server1`

```
Host server1
    HostName 172.160.189.196
    User admin
    Port 353

Host server2
    HostName 254.216.34.18
    User user
    Port 22
```

This is the command I give:

```
sed -i '0,/RE/s/HostName .*/HostName 14.208.54.132/' .ssh/config
```

Comment: What's `/RE/` ?

Comment: `0,/re/` allows the regex to match on the very first line also. In other words: such an address will create a range from the 1st line up to and including the line that matches `re` - whether `re` occurs on the 1st line or on any subsequent line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `sed` range:

```
sed -i '/Host server1/,/HostName/ s/HostName .*/HostName 14.208.54.132/' .ssh/config
```

This will replace `HostName` in the range of lines between `Host server1` and the first occurrence of `HostName`, which I think is what you want.

Comment: I've tried all three answers and they work, but I choose this for the simple reason that it uses sed and has a rather simple syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '$2=="server1" {f=1} f && /HostName/ {$0="    HostName 14.208.54.132";f=0} 1' file
Host server1
    HostName 14.208.54.132
    User admin
    Port 353

Host server2
    HostName 254.216.34.18
    User user
    Port 22
```

Comment: This might fail if you have a line like "User userver1"

Answer (score 0):

While awk is generally known to work on lines, it actually works with records, by default lines. A record can be defined by a record separator `RS`. If this variable is empty, it assumes that a record is given by text-blocks separated by one or more empty lines. With this you can do the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS=OFS="\n";ORS="\n\n"}
     ($1~/server1/) {sub(/Hostname[^\n]*\n/,"Hostname 14.208.54.132" OFS)}
     1' file
```

This is not short, but conceptually clean.
Obviously, you have to update the regex to match the hostname such that it is unique. If you also have a hostname `server1a`, then you will have to make sure that `($1~/server1/)` does not match that.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\<server1\>/{:a;n;/HostName/!ba;s/\S\+/14.208.54.132/2}' file
```

Focus on a line containing `server1` then read additional lines until one containing `HostName` and substitute the second field for the desired result.